# What does the Extended Memory Address ability do in an iOS app?

Tags: ios, xcode

I can't find any documentation on this ability. What are the differences between this and the "increased memory limit" ability, and what are the benefits of enabling it?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_developer_kernel_extended-virtual-addressing